# Why Python2.7 would crash when I convert caffe model to Apple's mlmodel

Tags: python, ios

In WWDC 2017,Apple announced support for trained ML models and support covert caffe model to apple's mlmodel. so I download a model which train by caffe and try to covert it to apple's mlmodel by follow apple coremltools python document. below is the code:

```
    import coremltools
    coreml_model =coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('oxford102.caffemodel','deploy.prototxt'),predicted_feature_name='class_labels.txt')
    coreml_model.save('oxford102.mlmodel')
```

but every time I click run, the python will crash, could anyone give me some help! thanks

[Python quit unexpectedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7vhz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue. You have to use a specific python version. Take a look at this: https://github.com/hollance/MobileNet-CoreML

Comment: thanks,it works, if any caffemodels have their own prototxt?